# Skip all test cases in a class based on condition in TestNG

Tags: testng

I have a condition in which I need to skip the test cases inside a class based on a condition in @BeforeClass. 
I know, this can be achieved by throwing skip exception in @BeforeClass

```
Class someClass {

      @BeforeClass
      public void beforeclass() {
           if(someThing.equals("Wrong")) {
                  throw new SkipException("Testing skip.");
           }
      }

      @Test
      public void test_method1() {
            //will be skipped if something is wrong.  
      }

      @Test
      public test_method2() {
           //will be skipped if something is wrong.
      }         
}
```

The problem with this approach is I need to write @BeforeClass method in each and every test class I have written.
Is there a listener for class invocation? 
or Is there a way to write one global beforeClass which has access to class name which is will call this method? 
I could not find anything for class invocation listener. Any other approach to solve this issue is also appreciated.

Comment: Can't you simply place those classes in separate suites and execute only some of those suites?

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz  That is one way of doing it, I have a large number of classes, it would be difficult to maintain suits for individual items. Is there any better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IClassListener](https://jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master-6.11-g1d80d76-102/javadoc/org/testng/IClassListener.html) should help you.